# Is it possible to get dataset which is returned by asp.net webservice on Android using SOAP ?

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server, soap, android-webservice

I have a webmethod which returns dataset from MS SQL.
I have an android application to get the dataset.
And is it possible to get the dataset using SOAP and how ?
Can anyone help me?
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml string with dataset values  and consume the web services Using SOAP in android application. there are so many examples available in internet.